# Attempting to Solve Semi-Infinite Solid, Solve is unable to solve

Tags: equation-solving

I am attempting to solve for the k, the thermal conductivity, based on the semi-infinite solid model. I have the following code:

```
tt = 60; ti = 100; t8 = 30; x = .01; t = 300; h = 200; p = 950; c = 1100;
```

and

```
Solve[.57143 == 
 Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t])] - 
 1*Exp[h*x/k + h^2/(p*c)*t/k]*
  Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t]) + h*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t]/k], k]
```

This returns:

```
Solve::inex: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help.
```

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Comment: I tried with exact numbers and got "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve." Looks like `Solve` is just not able to do it. I'm not sure what could be done.

Comment: I suppose you can find a numerical solution though, by inspection there are roots around 2, so `FindRoot[f[k] == 0.57143, {k, 1.6}]` should return one of them. Here `f[k]` is your expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tt = 60; ti = 100; t8 = 30; x = 0.01; t = 300; h = 200; p = 950; c = 1100;
```

You can use [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) by specifying a range for `k`

```
NSolve[{.57143 == 
   Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t])] - 
    1*Exp[h*x/k + h^2/(p*c)*t/k]*
     Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t]) + h*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t]/k], 0 < k < 10}, k]

(* {{k -> 1.83181}, {k -> 3.45194}} *)
```

The same two values can be obtained with [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) by using different initial estimates

```
FindRoot[.57143 == 
    Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t])] - 
     1*Exp[h*x/k + h^2/(p*c)*t/k]*
      Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t]) + 
        h*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t]/k], {k, #}] & /@ {2, 3}

(* {{k -> 1.83181}, {k -> 3.45194}} *)
```

You can also use [`FindMinimum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMinimum.html). Like `FindRoot`, it will require initial estimates.

```
FindMinimum[{Abs[.57143 - (Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t])] - 
         1*Exp[h*x/k + h^2/(p*c)*t/k]*
          Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t]) + h*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t]/k])], 
     0 < k < 10}, {k, #}][[2]] & /@ {2, 4}

(* {{k -> 1.83181}, {k -> 3.45194}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a transcendental equation.  Use FindRoot.

```
tt = 60; ti = 100; t8 = 30; x = 1/100; t = 300; h = 200; p = 950; c = 1100;

eq = 0.57143 - (Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[(k*t)/(p*c)])] - 
    Exp[(h*x)/k + (h^2*t)/((p*c)*k)]*Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[(k*t)/(p*c)]) + 
       (h*Sqrt[(k*t)/(p*c)])/k])

Plot[eq, {k, .1, 5}]
```

[image]

```
FindRoot[eq, {k, 1.8}]
(*{k -> 1.8318129956987919}*)

FindRoot[eq, {k, 3.5}]
(*{k -> 3.4519389939465204}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you rationalize the machine numbers (.01 and .57143) you'll instead get this error message which is the real problem:

`NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.`

Use FindRoot to get the roots around 2 and 3.5, which we can see from plotting the function.

```
tt=60;ti=100;t8=30;x=.01;t=300;h=200;p=950;c=1100;
eqn=(.57143==Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t])]-1*Exp[h*x/k+h^2/(p*c)*t/k]*Erfc[x/(2*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t])+h*Sqrt[k/(p*c)*t]/k])
Plot[eqn,{k,0,10}]
FindRoot[eqn,{k,2}]
FindRoot[eqn,{k,3.5}]
```